# Compose for RabbitMQ support for WebSocket

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is Compose for RabbitMQ integrated with WebSocket? That would require the STOMP plugin to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can request that the STOMP plugin is enabled by raising a support ticket.